# A vector $x∈X$ has coordinates $x_B=⟨2,−7,−10⟩$. What is $x_J$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, coordinate-systems, transition-matrix

[image]

I'm stuck on this question because $PJ<---B$ isn't given. 
If it helps the previous question asked to find $x_G$ which I found to be $<-2,-11,-17>$. 
I would really appreciate your help. Thank you

Comment: Transform to basis H, then apply the inverse of one of the given transformations to get from there to basis J.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

- $x_H=P_{HB}x_B$
- $x_J=P_{JH}x_H$
- $P_{JH}=P_{HJ}^{-1}$